# VBS - How to wait for a Windows Settings App to finish?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I'm building a custom setup for a set of Windows10 tablets by VBS scripts.
This setup is a sequence of calls that open some Windows Settings apps like the following:

```
start ms-settings:dateandtime
start ms-settings:camera
....
```

I'd like that, of course, each command waits the end of previous one.
If I use the

```
shell.run("ms-settings:dateandtime")
```

command with the wait set, I receive the error 'Unable to wait for process'.
If i run the command:

```
shell.exec("start ms-settings:dateandtime /wait")
```

I recevice the error: the system cannot find the file specified.
The same if i use the .Run  command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this will work as is in a tablet (I can only test on desktop), but you can use it as a starting point

```
Option Explicit

    Call ShowSettingsAndWait ( "ms-settings:dateandtime" )


Function ShowSettingsAndWait( setting )

    ' Default return value
    ShowSettingsAndWait = False 

    ' Resolve executable file and start required setting panel    
    Dim executable
    With WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        executable = Replace( _ 
            .ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%systemroot%\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe") _ 
            , "\", "\\" _ 
        )
        Call .Run( setting )
    End With 

    ' Wait for the process to start 
    Call WScript.Sleep( 500 )

    ' Instantiate WMI
    Dim wmi, query
    Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

    ' Search for SystemSettings executable
    Dim process, processID
    query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ExecutablePath='" & executable & "'"
    processID = - 1
    For Each process In wmi.ExecQuery( query )
        processID = process.processID
    Next 
    ' If not found, leave 
    If processID < 0 Then 
        Exit Function
    End If 

    ' Request process termination events
    Dim events
    query = "Select * From __InstanceDeletionEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"
    Set events = wmi.ExecNotificationQuery( query )

    ' Wait for the process to end
    Dim lastEvent
    Do While True
        WScript.Echo "."
        Set lastEvent = events.NextEvent
        If lastEvent.TargetInstance.ProcessID = processID Then 
            Exit Do 
        End If 
    Loop

    ' Done, everything was 
    ShowSettingsAndWait = True 
End Function
```